# Hide the clock on the iPhone 6+ lockscreen

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there no way to hide the clock on the iPhone 6+ lock screen?

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible without jailbreaking.

Answer (score -1):

I did this for my gf with some simple photoshopping, works like a charm, you will never see the time again.

- http://images.fzilla.com/images/renaa.png
- http://images.fzilla.com/images/zsunnyslut.png

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you actually did so others can reproduce it with images of their own?